# How to fetch woocommerce highest price and lowest price in custom template page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

$max_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby'=>'meta_value_num', 'order'=>'DESC','meta_key'=>'_price','posts_per_page'=>1) );

if(have_posts()){

while ($max_query->have_posts()){

$max_query->the_post();

$maxp = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true );

}

I am using this and its worked perfectly but how to retrieve max or min price woocommerce without using wp query? actually I am using it for price range slider(dynamically).

Comment: You want to retrieve products with prices between the given max and min price? Like a filter? You will need `meta_query` for that.

Comment: Have you thought about using the REST API instead https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

Comment: @Abhik No, first I want to bring the highest and lowest price of woocommerce products.Ex: product price start from 10 and highest is 150.so I just want only 10 and 150 first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
$products = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'=> '_price',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
));

$highest = $products[array_key_first($products)];
$lowest = $products[array_key_last($products)];

$highest_price = get_post_meta( $highest->ID, '_price', true );
$lowest_price = get_post_meta( $lowest->ID, '_price', true );
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhik. it work like a charm. Thanks a lot man....:)